# How do I prevent Windows from regenerating a deleted binary file?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-registry, hotspot

I often use the Windows Mobile Hotspot. Recently, devices that I connected to this network were unable to access the Internet (despite appearing "connected").

The only successful solution that I found was the second recommendation [here](https://thegeekpage.com/fix-mobile-hotspot-not-working-in-windows-10/), which suggests deleting the H`HostedNetworkSettings` binary file from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WlanSvc\Parameters\HostedNetworkSettings\` from the device generating the hotspot.

My Internet connection was fabulous after this. However, the key seems to regenerate every few days (and consequently, the hotspot stops working), and I have to go in to the registry editor and delete it again. Is there any way to prevent the key from being recreated so that I don't need to keep deleting it?

Comment: The usual advice is not to delete the `HostedNetworkSettings` registry key, but to delete the DWORD item by the same name inside it, then reboot. If that doesn't help, in an elevated CMD try `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`.

Comment: @harrymc I misspoke; edited the question to correct the error.

Comment: Did the command help?

Comment: @harrymc hard to say; If it doesn't go back to how it was before, then yes.

Comment: Let me know if it helped, so I can add a verified answer for future readers.

Comment: @harrymc it appears that the command worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To totally disable hosted networks so they don't come back,
run the following command in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd):

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
```